# If Linq query is Null return System.Int32.MinValue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to do a LINQ query on a field to determine the highest number than add one to it.  However, if there is nothing in the table it is crashing on me.  I have tried two separate ways to fix this problem:

```
int? tn = db.Tickets.Max(t => t.TicketNumber);
if (tn == null)
{
     ticket.TicketNumber = db.Tickets.Max(t => t.TicketNumber) + 1;
}
     else
{
     ticket.TicketNumber = System.Int32.MinValue + 1;
}
```

and

```
ticket.TicketNumber = db.Tickets.Max(t => t.TicketNumber) + 1 ?? System.Int32.MinValue + 1;
```

I have tried a few other ways but they all are minor changes to these two methods.  The error that I received on the former one is:

> Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why would you want to use int.MinValue rather than zero?

Comment: My supervisor said it is better coding.

Comment: But then your first ticket number will be -2,147,483,647.  I'm not sure that's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add `1` and `null`. Try:

```
ticket.TicketNumber = (db.Tickets.Max(t => t.TicketNumber) ?? Int32.MinValue) + 1;
```

**UPDATE**

You can only use `??` when there's a nullable involved. It appears here that you're always going to get *some value* back other than null. You might try something like:

```
var maxTicketNumber = db.Tickets.Max(t => t.TicketNumber);
ticket.TicketNumber = maxTicketNumber == default(int) ? Int32.MinValue : maxTicketNumber;
```

That just compares your number from the database with the default for an int if no real value is provided (`0`). That's essentially what you would get rather than null, since the property is not nullable. However, `0` may be a perfectly valid value, in which case you wouldn't want to use this code. It really depends on what you're actually trying to achieve. Perhaps if you provide more information in your question, we'll be able to assist you better.

Comment: Chris, thank you for all your help (not only on this question) but in the past as well. 

I am receiving an error with this code suggestion saying, "Operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type int and type int"

Comment: Is `TicketNumber` a nullable-int?

Comment: @TimSchmelter That would imply that your property of TicketNumber is not nullable. Cast to nullable type with (int?). (db.Tickets.Max(t => (int?)t.TicketNumber) ?? Int32.MinValue) + 1;

Comment: You're still missing a key issue.  A Max of an int wants to return an int.  If there are no rows in the db, it throws an exception because it cannot assign a null to an int.  The other answers that cast TicketNumber to a nullable int allow Max to return a null.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
ticket.TicketNumber = db.Tickets.Max(t => (int?)t.TicketNumber).GetValueOrDefault(int.MinValue) + 1;
```

Note the `int?` cast, if you don't put it you'll get the same exception if the table does not contain records. Btw, the full exception message is

> The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Answer (score 1):

```
int? tn = db.Tickets.Max(t => (int?) t.TicketNumber).GetValueOrDefault(int.MinValue) + 1;

                              ^^^^^^
```

The `Enumerable.Max(IEnumerable<int>)` overload doesn't allow for empty enumerables because it returns `int`, which cannot hold `null`. The `Enumerable.Max(IEnumerable<int?>)` overload does allow for empty enumerables.

Note that it's pretty uncommon to start with `int.MinValue + 1` -- did you perhaps want `0` instead of `int.MinValue`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [`DefaultIfEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419(v=vs.100).aspx), you just need to select the `TicketNumber` before:

```
ticket.TicketNumber = db.Tickets
    .Select(t => t.TicketNumber)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(Int32.MinValue)
    .Max() + 1;
```

The use of `DefaultIfEmpty` with a custom fallback value prevents an exception at `Enumerable.Max` because the sequence is never empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework as your back end, this Linq statement (although it looks like a sledgehammer on a nut) should translate to a reasonably efficient SQL query:

```
ticket.TicketNumber = db.Tickets.OrderByDescending(t => t.TicketNumber).FirstOrDefault() + 1;
```

The use of `FirstOrDefault` means that you actually get zero when there are no existing entries (your `TicketNumber` field is non-nullable, and its default is `0`), but as I said in the comments, that means that your first ticket number is `1`, which seems like a more realistic value that `int.MinValue + 1`.